# Extracting Data from non-Structured String in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, feature-engineering

everyone. I´m working with a Job Board dataset and I intend to turn the "Salary Offered" column into something I can use to make calculations, comparisons and predictions. I have five different cases for the data in the column:

-Yearly Salaries within a range (YSWR)

IE:£15,000 - £17,000 per annum

-Hourly salaries within a range (HSWR)

IE:£22.00 - £26.00 per hour

-Yearly salaries with specific values (YSWSV)

IE:£18,323 per annum

Hourly salaries with specific values (HSWSV)

IE £26.00 per hour

-Salary not Specified/Salary Negotiable/Competitive Salary

[image: Dataset]

I need to preprocess this field into:

-One column that indicates either the salary is yearly or hourly

-Two columns indicating the minimun/maximun salary(0 for non specified values and equal values for the cases that are not in a range)

Any Idea where to start? .I am working with python and PANDAS. I am a begginer when it comes to data preprocessing .

Thanks in advance.

Felix

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regular expression` to get the values and then implement the logic using `if=else`

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['£16,000 per annum'],
                   ['£25.0 per annum'], 
                   ['£19,000 per annum'],
                   ['£26.0 per annum'], 
                   ['Salary not specified'],
                  ['Competetive salary']], columns=['salary_offered'])


def apply_conditions(s):
    v = re.findall(r'^£(\d+,?\d+.?\d+)', s)
    if(len(v) == 0): # that means salary not specified
        return [0,0,'not specified'] #[min, max, salary]
    else:
        v = v[0]
        # replace ',' with '' so that we can parse
        v = v.replace(',', '')
        v = float(v)
        if(15000 < v < 17000):
            return [15000, 17000, v]
        elif(22 < v < 26):
            return [22, 26, v]
        elif(v == 18323):
            return [18323, 18323, v]
        elif(v == 26):
            return [26, 26, v]
        else:
            return [0, 0, 'not in range']
        
df['salary_offered'] = df['salary_offered'].apply(lambda x: apply_conditions(x))
df = pd.DataFrame(df['salary_offered'].to_list(), columns=['minimum', 'maximum', 'value'])
```

```
from

salary_offered
0   £16,000 per annum
1   £25.0 per annum
2   £19,000 per annum
3   £26.0 per annum
4   Salary not specified
5   Competetive salary
```

```
to

    minimum maximum value
0   15000   17000   16000
1   22      26  25
2   0       0   not in range
3   26      26  26
4   0   0   not specified
5   0   0   not specified
```